# jQuery UI - how to restore the dropped draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 Divs which I can drag to an image of a trash can. Once the user releases the mouse the Div is dropped otherwise it is reverted to its original location, here's my code:

```
<div id="draggables">
    <div id="d1">
        <header>A</header>
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        <header>B</header>
    </div>
    <div id="d3">
        <header>C</header>
    </div>
</div>


<img src="trash.jpg" id="trash" class="semitransparent" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
    // draggables...

    $("#d1,#d2,#d3").draggable({
        revert:"invalid"
    });

    $("#trash").droppable({

        activeClass:"opaque",
        drop: function(event, ui){

            ui.draggable.fadeOut(function(){
                ui.draggable.remove();

            });
        }

    });

});
```

I also apply an activeClass to the image of the trashcan so the user realises that they can drag / the functionality is active. However I'd like to extend my code so when a Div is dropped it's restored to its original position within the "draggables" Div. I'm unsure whether to use a helper clone on the draggable elements or within the function somehow append to the "draggables" Div. Does anyone have any advice? Is there a method like : `ui.draggable.restore();` I can use?

If my wording is bad please let me know and I'll rephase the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `revert` option:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert

Comment: I'm using that with my draggables, how are you suggesting I use it again?

Comment: If you set revert to true the element will be restored to it's original position after the drop.

Comment: However I thought that revert will only occur if the draggable has not been dropped on a droppable? I could be confused here

Comment: Well i'd say the will probably revert when you set that to valid or true. But as you remove them from the dom they just never get the chance to revert ;)

Comment: It will only revert when not dropped on a valid droppable.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that the image doesn't want to be a droppable, the script seems to work...

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ56q/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code that I adopted to use in my projects.

Html:

```
<div class="N_COn_USER" name="moh1234"> 
<img class="delople" src="_files/us.png" />
</div>

<div class="N_COn_USER" name="demo1234"> 
<img class="delople" src="_files/us.png" />
</div>

<div class="N_COn_USER" name="foo1234"> 
<img class="delople" src="_files/us.png" />
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var id ;
    id = $(".N_COn_USER").draggable({    // the draggable div
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
    id = $(this).attr("name");  // we name each draggable item with its ID or any unique identifier. And here, we grab that value ..
    }
}).attr("name");

    $("#dropable_file").droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function() { 

    var agree=confirm('Permantly delete '+ id2 +"?");
    if (agree) {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'unfollow',
        data: 'u=' + id,   // we send that ID to a processing page controller 
        type: 'post',
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg == 'bad') // Message Sent, check and redirect
            {                // and direct to the success page
            $("#msgbox").html('').addClass('good');
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            {
                //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                $(this).html('Tcxfgg').removeClass().addClass('error').fadeTo(300,1); // if not deleted, show an error!

            });    
            }
            else  // if everything went perfectly 
            {
            $("div[name="+id+"]").fadeOut("slow");  // the item with that unique name gets faded out on success. 
            $("span[name="+id+"]").fadeOut("slow"); // picture of it also should have its own name if it lives outside that DIV.


            }
        }
        });

    } else {
        return false;
    }

    }
    });
});
```

I hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

helper: "clone" is the way to go and when you made up your mind whether to remove it from original location you just remove it using .remove()